# Why webapp2 is default framework in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I wonder why webapp2 is default python framework in GAE? Are there some important advantages of using webapp2 on GAE versus other python frameworks,or this was just a random solution? I read it is supported by google,does that mean that it will be more suitable for GAE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because webapp2 is a superset of the webapp engine that was designed by the GAE team at google. [This text helps](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/#credits):

> webapp2 is a superset of webapp, created by the App Engine team.
>   Because webapp2 is intended to be compatible with webapp, the official
>   webapp documentation is valid for webapp2 too. Parts of this
>   documentation were ported from the App Engine documentation, written
>   by the App Engine team and licensed under the Creative Commons
>   Attribution 3.0 License. webapp2 has code ported from Werkzeug and
>   Tipfy. webapp2_extras has code ported from Werkzeug, Tipfy and Tornado
>   Web Server. The Sphinx theme mimics the App Engine documentation. This
>   library was not created and is not maintained by Google.

GAE does support other frameworks, but webapp2 is the the most compatible.